# Create field Sequelize varchar

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a field IDENTITY with a size of 25, but in the SQL server database it looks like nvarchar.

Is there any possibility of creating as "varchar"?

```
 IDENTITY: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(25),
  },
```

Comment: it's a Sequelize bug that was never fixed: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6036

Comment: Yeap, One solution was to change for type: Sequelize.STRING(25).toSql()